# Is there an easy way in eclipse to tell what scm revision made a change in the line the cursor is in?

Tags: java, eclipse, version-control, subversive

I am aware of the Team History view in eclipse that will show me all previous revisions of a file, and highlight the changes.

However, I often find a change, and would like to know who did it and what their commit comment was. Currently, I have to sieve through the history view. Is there a plugin or a built-in way of figuring this out faster? I am currently using SVN and Subversive, but of course, the more general the solution the better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Subclipse plugin: Right click on the source file, select in appearing menu Team -> Show Annotation... then the author and revision can be seen for each line where your cursor is currently on.

Answer (score 4):

In the team menu there should be an option 'Annotate' or 'Blame'. It will introduce a colored bar at the side of the editor. You can hover over it to see information about the last commit changing that line.